# make is truncating some compile commands under cygwin

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin

I'm working on an electricity meter with a large existing code base and trying to introduce some automated testing. I've written a python script that decodes a Keil project file for ARM and generates a makefile. So most of the defines and include paths are actually defined in the keil project file. Well actually quite a few defines are added by me.

Said makefile is wonderful except it strips the first few characters from some compile commands. The two lines below are examples of a good compile command, and a bad one. It's easy to see "g++ -" has been stripped from the beginning of the compile command.

It's always those 5 characters. The one hint I have is that the files that fail have relatively long paths.

Defining SHELL=/bin/bash changes nothing.

g++ -c ../Project/External/HAL/src/HWRNG.cpp -o obj/HWRNG.o -D **IO="" -D __I="" -D __packed="" -D ubyte8="unsigned long long" -std=c++11 -w -fpermissive -D __GNUC** -D __USE_C99_MATH -D LOGICAL_NAME_REFERENCING -D EOSAL_NAMESPACE=CosemMeter -D USE_RTX -D STM32F412xG -D USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -D HSE_VALUE=24000000 -D DEBUG_UART -D OLD_MCOR -D ENABLE_LTE_MODEM -I ../trace -I ../trace/EOSAL/src -I patch/include -I ../Project -I ../Project/Hardware -I ../Project/External/CosemServerLib -I ../Project/External/CosemServerLib/Project -I ../Project/External/CosemServerLib/External -I ../Project/External/HAL/inc -I ../Project/External/HAL/STM/32F4xx/drivers/inc -I ../Project/External/STM32F4xx/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I ../Project/External/STM32F4xx/CMSIS/Include -I ../Project/External/STM32F4xx/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -I ../Project/lib -I ../Project/lib/RTX/inc -I ../Project/lib/RTX/inc/RTL -I ../Project/lib/Mocana/src -I ../Project/Middlewares/Segger/USBH -I ../Project/Middlewares/Segger/Inc -I ../Project/SeggerCfg -I ../Project/LTE/inc

c ../Project/External/HAL/STM/32F4xx/drivers/src/EXTI_Driver.c -o obj/EXTI_Driver.o -D __IO="" -D __I="" -D __packed="" -D ubyte8="unsigned long long" -D __USE_C99_MATH -D LOGICAL_NAME_REFERENCING -D EOSAL_NAMESPACE=CosemMeter -D USE_RTX -D STM32F412xG -D USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -D HSE_VALUE=24000000 -D DEBUG_UART -D OLD_MCOR -D ENABLE_LTE_MODEM -I ../trace -I ../trace/EOSAL/src -I patch/include -I ../Project -I ../Project/Hardware -I ../Project/External/CosemServerLib -I ../Project/External/CosemServerLib/Project -I ../Project/External/CosemServerLib/External -I ../Project/External/HAL/inc -I ../Project/External/HAL/STM/32F4xx/drivers/inc -I ../Project/External/STM32F4xx/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I ../Project/External/STM32F4xx/CMSIS/Include -I ../Project/External/STM32F4xx/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc -I ../Project/lib -I ../Project/lib/RTX/inc -I ../Project/lib/RTX/inc/RTL -I ../Project/lib/Mocana/src -I ../Project/Middlewares/Segger/USBH -I ../Project/Middlewares/Segger/Inc -I ../Project/SeggerCfg -I ../Project/LTE/inc
/bin/sh: c: command not found
make: [Makefile:167: obj/EXTI_Driver.o] Error 127 (ignored)

Answer (score 0):

I was on the road for the last few weeks and showed my problem to a colleague yesterday. He immediately noticed it was the C compiles so behaving and the C++ were behaving properly. I had misdefined the CC symbol for C comiles.